# Defining Java variables that only accept a specific range of values

Tags: java, variables, static, field, final

Is there a **built-in** way to define fields/variables accepting values in a specific range?
I mean a way of resolving it in **compile-time**.

For example, defining a *double* variable that only takes values between 1-10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, since in compilation time there is no way to know if your software logic will produce values out of range. And in runtime there is no implementation for it supported by the native sdk. You can however wrap the type classes (e.g. Create class `MyInteger` with an `Integer` instance as a member wrapped by range verification methods in the `MyInteger` class)

Comment: You can wrap an `Integer`, but you can't extend it; it's `final`.

Answer (score 5):

The closest you can get is

1) create an Enum for your range of values, that's what Enums are for.

```
public Enum MyVals {
   ONE(1)
   TWO(2)
   ...

   private int val;
   MyVals(int val) {
      this.val = val;
   }
}
```

[see this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).  Of course this will only work if the values are discrete (i.e. not floats)

2) make the field private and write a smart setter that blows up on an unacceptable value.

```
public void setVal(int val) {
   if (val < 0 || val > 10) throw....;
   this.val = val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While not a compile time option for specifying a range, another approach is to use a validation framework like [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html). You annotate your field using an annotation like [@Range(min=, max=)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html_single/). You use a validator object's [validate method](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-obtaining-validator) to validate you object.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what you're talking about is an enum, which allows you to specify a fix set of values.  There is no way to declare an Integer, but limit the valid values that it can have.  You could create your own type and enforce such a restriction, though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use enums for such set. but i guess u also want some meaningful mapping for values. in that case, maintain a lookup HashTable, with key as enums, and value whatever you want.